# tf.LookupException: "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist

Tags: ros, transforms, tf2, rospy, transform-listener

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

I am new with ros tf's and already worked myself threw the tf tutorials. (I am using ros indigo)
As my first test with tf's after the tutorial I wrote 2 small nodes.

The first one is sending a tf:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf

class tf_firsttry_pub_class():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('tf_firsttry_pub')
        now = rospy.Time.now()
        br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            br.sendTransform((1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), rospy.Time(), 'one','base_link')
            rospy.Rate(50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        tf_firsttry_pub_class()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

The second is listening to the tf:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf

class tf_firsttry_listen_class():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('tf_firsttry_listen')
        listener = tf.TransformListener()
        now = rospy.Time.now()
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            (trans,rot)=listener.lookupTransform('/base_link','/one',rospy.Time(0))
            print trans

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        tf_firsttry_listen_class()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

When starting the second node this error occurs:

> line 11, in **init**
> (trans,rot)=listener.lookupTransform('/base_link','/one',rospy.Time(0))
> tf.LookupException: "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

I already found in a different question that a `try: except:` shell around the listener could help as it may only fail at the beginning but that doesn't help.

As you see the code is easy but I am totally stuck. I think I misunderstood something but can't figure out what.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240427/tf.lookupexception:-%22base_link%22-passed-to-lookuptransform-argument-target_frame-does-not-exist./) by [Bant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27610/bant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At first glance, your frames are different in the first node than the second node. 'Baselink' in the first node became '/base_link' in the second node and 'One' became '/one'. The strings identify the frames and when you lookup the transform you need to look for the frames with the same string that you publish them with.

---

Originally posted by [alexvs](https://answers.ros.org/users/22322/alexvs/) with karma: 91 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27610/bant/) on 2016-07-27**:
Sorry about that. I got messed up with the names during testing. But even with the same names the error remains.

**Comment by [Bant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27610/bant/) on 2016-07-27**:
Fixed. A wait for transform in the second code and a rospy.rate(150) in the first one made it working. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

I fixed it and now it feels way to easy.
But I will leave the solution here anyway. Maybe it helps the next person starting with tf's.

The running code: first node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf

class tf_firsttry_pub_class():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('tf_firsttry_pub')
        now = rospy.Time.now()
        br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
        R = rospy.Rate(150)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            br.sendTransform((1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1), rospy.Time(), 'One','base_link')      
            R.sleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        tf_firsttry_pub_class()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

second node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf


class tf_firsttry_listen_class():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('tf_firsttry_listen')
        listener = tf.TransformListener()
        now = rospy.Time.now()
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            listener.waitForTransform('/base_link','/One',rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(4.0))
            (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/base_link', '/One', rospy.Time(0))
            print trans


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        tf_firsttry_listen_class()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Note the `R = rospy.Rate(150)` and `R.sleep()` in the first code and the `listener.waitForTransform` in the second!

---

Originally posted by [Bant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27610/bant/) with karma: 103 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-09-26**:
Thanks - far, far too many question topics end with "thanks; it's working" and no code left to help other people!

**Comment by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on 2019-12-27**:
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! SOLVED MY ISSUE!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason for this error is that your listener sometimes cannot catch the transform frame which you want for transformation due to latency issue in rate with which a broadcaster is publishing.There are two solutions to this problem

1.to create a timer for your callback listener with litlle more duration as compared to what you were using before.

2.using a try-catch block

---

Originally posted by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) with karma: 25 on 2019-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1